# Server hangs when crawling

Tags: node.js, web-crawler, node-request, node-crawler

My server is hang after many requests. 
I tried change UserAgent, rateLimit, maxConnections etc. 
I don't know why my server was hangs after ~1000 requests. 
When I stop my application server works now.

Where is a problem? I use scrapoxy OVH Cloud. http://scrapoxy.io

Ubuntu, MongoDB, NodeJS

```
function otodomParser(db, urls, type) {
var otodomCities = new Crawler({
    rateLimit: 1000,
    maxConnections: 10,
    callback: function(error, res, done) {
        if(error) {
            console.log(error);    
        } else {
            let pages = 3;

            var otodomAdvsUrl = new Crawler({
                rateLimit: 1000,
                maxConnections: 10,
                callback: function(error, res, done) {
                    if(error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    } else {
                        // parsing
                    }
                    done();
                }
            });

            for(let p = 1; p <= pages; p++) {
                otodomAdvsUrl.queue({
                    url: res.options.url + '&page=' + p,
                    proxy: proxy_url,
                    gzip: true,
                    headers: {
                        'User-Agent': 'Chrome/59.0.3071.115',
                        'Proxy-Connections': 'keep-alive',
                        'Host': 'www.otodom.pl'
                    },
                    parameter1: res.options.parameter1
                });
            }
        }
        done();
    }
});

for(let i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
    otodomCities.queue({
        url: urls[i].url,
        proxy: proxy_url,
        gzip: true,
        headers: {
            'User-Agent': 'Chrome/59.0.3071.115',
            'Proxy-Connections': 'keep-alive',
            'Host': 'www.otodom.pl'
        },
        parameter1: urls[i].city_id
    });
}
}
```

Comment: error: CRAWLER Error Error: socket hang up when fetching

Comment: The reason might differs, but from what I have seen from your code you should put some wait time after the request since fetching the data needs time and you are not waiting for the response to be fetched, doing it your way you will end up with a lot of requests going on and not fetched yet or parsed!, also why don't you use async/await syntax it would be a lot easier to read, maintain and debug!

Comment: @mohammadmohammad you mean async requests?

Comment: no use promises syntax here is a [https://medium.com/dev-bits/writing-neat-asynchronous-node-js-code-with-promises-32ed3a4fd098], you are stuck in a callback hell, all of the requests are async operations. just consider to put some time slot before going and fetching new request it might help you!

Comment: @mohammadmohammad now I get ESOCKETTIMEDOUT

Comment: You will likely need to write code to limit the number of http requests in process at any given time to something that your server can handle and you probably should also limit the number of requests to any given domain at once to keep from getting denied access by the target host.  Then, start with both of those limit numbers set low and experiment with how high you can raise them without getting errors.

Comment: @jfriend00 This is scrapoxy problem or my crawler?

Comment: Log from proxy: error: [Master] Error: request error from target (GET https://www.otodom.pl/oferta/chorzow-centrum-wolnosci-lokal-uzytkowy-240-m2-ID418ql.html on instance xxx): message=Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established, stack=Error: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established code=ECONNRESET, path=undefined, host=www.otodom.pl, port=undefined, localAddress=undefined

Comment: ECONNRESET can happen when a target server determines that there are too many incoming requests and that is the quickest way to "hang up" on an incoming connection.  If your crawler is supposed to be limiting the number of simultaneous requests, then you need to either lower the value you have it configured for or check that it's actually doing what it's supposed to.

Comment: @jfriend00 so i have too many incoming connections to proxy server? how i can change this limit? (Ubuntu)

Comment: I have no idea what scraproxy's limits are or how it handles things when you give it a lot of requests.  You'd have to do some research on it to learn more.  Since you have so many moving pieces, I'd probably simplify things and limit the simultaneous requests until you get things working and then add more complexity/connections once it's working.

Comment: @jfriend00 so if I change the proxy to other what will handle a lot of incoming connections will work?

Comment: @mezawari - I don't know.  You're guessing what the issue is.  You're going to have to test various configurations to find out which part of this fairly involved system is causing the issue.

Comment: @jfriend00 now work but i randomly gets 200 or 403 when i use proxy

Comment: 403 sounds like you don't have rights to see that resource.  It would typically mean that the server understands your authenitcation (if there was any), but you are specifically not allowed to see that resource.  This all assumes the server is returning the correct status codes.  I supposed it's also possible that the proxy is making the 403 too for some reason.  200 is success, right?

Comment: @jfriend00 on the same urls i have to change 200 or 403